# Unix shell script error in crontab

Tags: bash, shell, unix, cron

I'm trying to schedule my shell script but when it triggered to process on a scheduled task, there is this error prompt. but when no files are to be process it just displays the echo command.

here is my code:

```
if [ "$(ls -A $path)" ]
    then
    for file_name in "$path"/*; do
        filebasename=$(basename "$file_name")


        prefix=${filebasename:0:4};

        if [ "$prefix" == "abcd" ] ; then

            mv  "$file_name" "$out"

        fi                          

    done


    else echo "No files available at $path"
fi
```

and this is the error:

```
SH:prefix=${filebasename:0:4}:0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command
```

Comment: The `${var:n:m}` expansion is not available in /bin/sh. You'd need to specify ksh or bash for that. Same with the `==` operator.

Comment: hi glenn thanks for this, but what should i do ? do i need to reconstruct the syntax for the code?

Comment: You can add #!/bin/bash to the first line in your script

Comment: You also have some other syntax errors. Paste your code into shellcheck.net for further tips

Comment: thanks for this @glennjackman

Answer (score 1):

You can write your code more simply this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0
if [[ -d "$path" ]]; then
  for file_name in "$path"/abcd*; do
    [[ -f "$file_name" ]] && { ((count++)); mv "$file_name" "$out"; }
  done
fi

if ((count == 0)); then
  echo "No files available at $path"
fi
```

The advantages:

- No need to parse the output of `ls`
- No need to do basename + substring for each file
- Skips any directories that have a name starting with `abcd`

In case you are not interested in knowing whether there were matching files or not, the whole thing can be written in a single line:

```
find "$path" -name "abcd*" -type f -exec mv "{}" "$out" \;
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the last suggestion, using `find`, works in any shell and does not require bash. Oh, and the `cd` is redundant (unless `$out` is relative to `$path`).

Comment: Thanks @ghoti.  I had to put in that `cd` because `find` wouldn't work without it on my Mac.

Comment: That sounds strange. `find` in macOS should work about the same way as everywhere else. What exactly was your command, and what error did you get? Was your `$out` in fact relative? Might want to read about `-execdir`. More about your answer.. You can avoid the `[[ -f ...` with a `shopt -s nullglob` (yes, even in bash 3). And you might want to include find's `-maxdepth` option too, to emulate the behaviour of a bash `for` loop without `globstar`.

Comment: The command depends on the values of the variables. You haven't mentioned the values of `$path` or `$out` that you tested with.

Comment: I used /tmp and /tmp/temp.  Added -maxdepth 1 as well.

Comment: On macOS, a `$path` of just `/tmp` might not have worked since that's a symlink to `/private/tmp`. If you set `path="/tmp/"` (trailing slash) it should *follow* the symlink rather than evaluating it as a file. Alternately, you could use the `-H` or `-L` option for `find`.

Comment: Great catch @ghoti.  Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

i use this code:
prefix=$(echo ${filebasename} | cut -c1-4)

instead of prefix=${filebasename:0:4};

now it completely running in my cronjob and no error as said earlier. thanks for the help guys ! :)